# Permutation of phone numbers starting at button x, ending at button y, and z numbers long

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying find the total number of permutations possible with a given x, y, and z. 
x is the initial number, y is the final number, and z is the total number of buttons pressed.
I am supposed to only move from number to number like the knight in chess, in an 'L' shape.
For example, if you just dialed a 1, the next number you dial has to be either a 6 or an 8. If you just dialed a 6, the next number must be a 1 or 7. 
Currently, my implementation outputs the correct answer for all the numbers I have given it. However, it is **god awful slow** because compute time is exponential. What I want to know is how I can compute this in linear time, more or less. z will always be between 1 and 100, inclusive.

```
##Computes the number of phone numbers one
##can dial that start with the digit x, end
##in the digit y, and consist of z digits in
##total. Output this number as a
##string representing the number in base-10.
##Must follow "knights rule" moves, like chess
##########_________##########
##########|1||2||3|##########
##########|_||_||_|##########
##########|4||5||6|##########
##########|_||_||_|##########
##########|7||8||9|##########
##########|_||_||_|##########
##########|_||0||_|##########
##########^^^^^^^^^##########
dict = {0: [4, 6], 1: [6, 8], 2: [7, 9], 3: [4, 8],
    4: [0, 3, 9], 5: [], 6: [0, 1, 7], 7: [2, 6], 8: [1, 3],
    9: [2, 4]}


def recAnswer(current, y, z, count, total):
    if count == z and current == y:
            total += 1
            return total
    count+=1
    if count > z:
            return total
    for i in dict.get(current):
            total = recAnswer(i, y, z, count, total)
    return total

def answer(x, y, z):
    if x == y:
            if z%2 == 0:
                    return '0'
    elif x == 5 or y == 5:
            if z == 1 and x == y:
                    return '1'
            else:
                    return '0'
    elif x%2 != 0 and y%2 == 0:
            if z%2 != 0:
                    return '0'
    elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 != 0:
            if z%2 != 0:
                    return '0'
    elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 ==0:
            if z%2 == 0:
                    return '0'
    elif x%2 != 0 and y%2 != 0:
            if z%2 == 0:
                    return '0'

    total = recAnswer(x,y,z,1,0)
    return str(total)

def test():
    for i in xrange(1,15,1):
            print i,":",answer(1,3,i)

    print answer(6, 2, 5)
    print answer(1, 6, 3)
    print answer(1, 1, 99)


test()
```

Comment: I've got some draft written for a quicker implementation... Is there an existing implementation to test the results?

Comment: For x=y= 3 and z=2, the movements could be (3,8,3), (3,4,3). Why are you returning zero? Am I missing something or are you counting the initial position as well?

Comment: [Same question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351539/permutation-of-phone-numbers-starting-at-button-x-ending-at-button-y-and-z-num)

Comment: @thepace I am counting the initial position as well. For x=y=3, z would have to be either 1, 3, 5, ... any odd number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cache dictionary provides the linear complexity you're looking for, since the number of cache accesses is bounded by `number_of_moves * z = 20 * z` and the number of `rec` calls is bounded by `number_of_keys * z = 10 * z`.

```
"""Solve the phone/chess paths problem from this question:
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71988
"""

# Move dictionary
MOVES = {0: [4, 6],
         1: [6, 8],
         2: [7, 9],
         3: [4, 8],
         4: [0, 3, 9],
         5: [],
         6: [0, 1, 7],
         7: [2, 6],
         8: [1, 3],
         9: [2, 4]}

# Cache implementation
def cache(func):
    """Standard cache decorator implementation."""
    cache_dct = {}
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in cache_dct:
            cache_dct[args] = func(*args)
        return cache_dct[args]
    return wrapper

# Recusive function 
@cache
def rec(x, y, z):
    """Recursively count the number of path
    to go from x to y in z moves.
    """
    if not z:
        return int(x == y)
    return sum(rec(x, y, z-1) for x in MOVES[x])

# Paths function
def paths(x, y, z):
    """Count the number of paths to go from x to y
    with z key strokes.
    """
    if not z:
        return 0
    return rec(x, y, z-1)

# Main execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    example = "paths(1, 1, 99)"
    print example + " = " + str(eval(example))
    # Output: paths(1, 1, 99) = 30810672576979228350316940764381184
```

Comment: Code only Reviews are frowned upon, could you please explain what you have done here and why?

Comment: This is great! Very fast!

Answer (score 1):

One probable solution could be to modify the code as this:

1. Have the code inside answer in another function, say, `isNotTraversalCandidate` which returns 0,1 if it the conditions confirm that no further traversal is required else it returns -1.
2. In `recAnswer()` use this function, `isNotTraversalCandidate()`, for the input `x`, `y`, `z` in every level. The recursive function should also verify the `x`, `y`, `z` with those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

## Remarks on original code

- Don't use `dict` as a variable name because it hides a useful built-in.
- You have written code to deal with various special easy cases before accomplishing acceptable worst case performance. That's premature optimization because a good algorithm might be fast enough for you in all cases.
- Regardless, I'll point out that all this

  ```
  elif x%2 != 0 and y%2 == 0:
          if z%2 != 0:
                  return '0'
  elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 != 0:
          if z%2 != 0:
                  return '0'
  elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 ==0:
          if z%2 == 0:
                  return '0'
  elif x%2 != 0 and y%2 != 0:
          if z%2 == 0:
                  return '0'
  ```

  is equivalent to this:

  ```
  elif (x + y + z) % 2 == 0:
      return '0'
  ```
- Returning a numeric result as a string is odd. `print` will convert to string automatically anyway.

## Alternative solution

Memoization (as pointed out by other answers) is a good solution and fits to your existing code. However, I'd like to propose a straightforward iterative solution. Basically, when  you know how many paths lead to each possible digit at some position, it is easy to compute the same for the next position by following the graph that represents the allowed moves. At the first position the digit is given so you assign a count of 1 to that.

```
from collections import defaultdict

GRAPH = {0: [4, 6], 1: [6, 8], 2: [7, 9], 3: [4, 8],
    4: [0, 3, 9], 5: [], 6: [0, 1, 7], 7: [2, 6], 8: [1, 3],
    9: [2, 4]}

def count_numbers(x, y, z):
    counts = {x: 1}

    for _ in range(z - 1):
        next_counts = defaultdict(int)
        for digit, n in counts.items():
            for neighbor in GRAPH[digit]:
                next_counts[neighbor] += n
        counts = next_counts      

    return counts.get(y, 0)
```